# C# wpf navigation pages behaviour issue

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Recently picked up WPF about a month ago , decided to design a small WPF navigation application. my design requires a _mainwindow with multiple tile buttons , and click event show a new page, page 1 or 2 which have different content and a back button  that takes screen back to the _mainwindow . I have total 5 pages in the application . The problem i am facing is , if i uses NavigationService i have to use pages only and its giving a default navigation bar that i do not require , secondly my design requires pages to be isolated rather to navigate 1 page to an other with navigation bar .

So my question is how can i be able to implement this design with my limited knowledge of WPF  or should i have to change the design .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the arrows.  You can hide them

```
<Page x:Class="Gabe2a.PageDocFieldDetail"
      ShowsNavigationUI="False"/>
```